# como podria hacer que un modal se muestre completo dentro de un iframe?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, jsp

Estoy trabajando dentro de un iframe y al hacer clic a
un check box me debe de arrojar un modal pero este sale
muy cargado a la izquierda y solo muestra la mitad y
a un que con css lo ponga en el centro solo muestra
la mitad del modal, dato curiso para mi, es que si muestro el
modal en un celular o tablet lo muestra completo y a
la mitad.

Saludos.
-----cambie el codigo

y ahora si con un boton si me muestra el modal
pero si ese mismo modal lo quiero mostrar
con un checkbox el modal lo manda al fondo 
y no puedo seleccionar el boton para cerrar.

```js
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
<script>
   $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked') ) {
      
       $("#myModal").modal('show');
          // $('#myModal').modal();  
            
           
        
        } else {
          
        }
    });
 
 </script>
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

 <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div
```

Comment: sin codigo no hay nada que se pueda hacer amigo

Comment: Deseas que abarque la totalidad de la pantalla o la totalidad exclusiva del iframe? Por favor agrega los enlaces necesarios para que bootstrap funcione no veo ni su hoja de estilos ni su .js, tampoco veo agregada la librería de jquery

Comment: Solo el iframe,en unos momentos las agrego.